# Laravel multiple apps share session

Tags: php, laravel, session, cookies, redis

I am trying to run 2 laravel apps on same domain and use same session, to keep user logged in when app changes. My apps concept:

- [**APP1**] app with Laravel 5.4, redis session driver and it uses domain:
  my-site.com
- [**APP2**] app with Laravel 8, redis session driver and it
  uses domain route: my-site.com/mysecondapp

I have made changes to files (now they have same settings in both apps):

```
config/session.php
config/cache.php
config/database.php
```

also I have set these .env attributes same in both apps:

```
APP_NAME=myapp
APP_KEY=base64:I5Cab6HUJdbaaaI0rWtGfBBLM/Yikvnc57+ShI4X8r0=
APP_URL=http://my-site.com
CACHE_DRIVER=redis
FILESYSTEM_DRIVER=local
QUEUE_CONNECTION=sync
SESSION_DRIVER=redis
SESSION_LIFETIME=120
SESSION_COOKIE=myapp_session
SESSION_DOMAIN=.my-app.com (also tried empty and my-app.com values)
and redis login settings are same
```

After all these changes, when I login in **APP1** and open custom page on **APP2** where I print out session()-all(), there is no session info from **APP1**.

Also when I print out Session::getId(), they are different on both apps.

If I login in **APP1** and open custom page on **APP2** where I run code:

```
Session::setId('Session ID from APP1 Session::getId()');
Session::start();
print_r(Session::getId());
print_r(session()->all());
```

Then I have all session info from **APP1**, but if you access other page in **APP2**, then session resets (I get new, different from **APP1** session ID and no session info from that app)

Any ideas how to make it work?

Thank you.

Comment: replace two lines `Session::start(); Session::setId('Session ID from APP1 Session::getId()');`

Comment: thank you for help, when I replace these two lines I get logout on APP1 and APP2 session reset (new session which has only token value)